# How to store variables in a string array in c++

Tags: c++

I am quite in to C++ and have a recent homework assignment which I need to store 1000 most common words into a string array. I was wondering how would I go about this. Here is my example code so far,

```
if(infile.good() && outfile.good())
    {
        //save 1000 common words to a string 

        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) 
        {
            totalWordsIn1000MostCommon++; 
            break; 
        }

        while (infile.good()) 
        {
            string commonWords[1000];
            infile >> commonWords;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not down-voting this, but your example code so far does not demonstrate sufficient effort. Did you work out a general approach to the problem? How do you plan on counting words?

Comment: How are you identifying the "most common words"? To me that sounds like you would want to read all the words, count the reoccurring words, sort by the highest count, then push the first thousand from the sorted collection into a `std::vector<std::string>` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <cstdio>
   #include <string>

   freopen(inputfileName,"r",stdin); 
   const int words = 1000;
   string myArr[words];
   for(int i=0;i<words;i++){
       string line;
       getline(cin,line);
       myArr[i] = line;      
   }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you hijack `cin` rather than opening a file stream?

Comment: Just a fancy way of doing it.

Comment: @AbhishekIyer, no it's not a "fancy" way of doing it - it's a totally redundant way of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop above does nothing at the beginning, just breaks at first iteration. It would be better if you'll read how to use loops in C++. Also take a look at the scopes of the variables in C++. In your case commonWords declared in `while` loop, so will be created each time and destroyed after each loop iteration.
What you want is something like this:

```
int i = 0;
std::string commonWords[1000];
while (i < 1000 && infile.good()) {
    infile >> commonWords[i];
    ++i;
}
```

I'm living the remaining part for you to complete your homework.

Comment: Thanks, I will retake a look at loops in C++. Thanks a lot for the help.